# JpaRepository findOne returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using the below code to retrieve a file from db using Spring Boot JPA. 
But it's returning null value.

PS. There is no problem with DB connection. I can save values using the repository but problem occurs while retrieving value using ID.

Can anyone please give me a solution ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetch/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Page> getData(@PathVariable String id) {
     try {
            FileDB file = fileRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));
            Document doc = file.getDocument();
            List<Page> pages = doc.getPages();
            return pages;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();
            return pages;
        }
}
```

Comment: Show the exception please if any

Comment: Show the class/interface of `fileRepository`

Comment: Getting Null pointer exception - java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Here is my fileRepository interface - public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository<FileDB, Long> {}

Comment: We need more detail, like on which line it happens

Comment: On line - FileDB file = fileRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));

Comment: How is your fileRepository initialised

Comment: is maybe `id` null?

Comment: No. There are 8 items on the DB.

Comment: Did you try `findById` instead of `findOne`?

Comment: @Autowired 
 FileRepository fileRepository; here is the fileRepository initaition. Lino

Comment: JpaRepository doen't have any findById method @Bennett

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. I've accidentally changed one variable type in the bean. That's why it was not getting anything from DB saved using previous bean. Thanks everyone.